# SQL how to determine count and sequence of self-joins given selection criteria

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have a key-value table named ATTR, where data related to a single logical record (identified
by a S#) are stored as key-value pairs.

```
table ATTR:
S#   KEY    VALUE
```

So, given criteria in psuedo-code:

```
Select S# Where k1 > 5
```

becomes

```
Select t1.S# 
from ATTR t1 
where t1.KEY = 'k1' AND t1.VALUE > 5
```

and so on. Practically all of my use cases involve one or more self-joins.

My question is - given a criteria, is there is a scientific approach to 
deduce the number of self-joins needed, and how to do so. Does it require
a rearrangement of the criteria (I would like to avoid such rejig - letting the
dbms query optimizer take care of that).

To give some illustrative examples

```
crit: where k1 > 5 OR k2 > 10
=> no extra join needed
Select t1.S# 
from ATTR t1 
where (t1.KEY = 'k1' AND t1.VALUE > 5) OR (t1.KEY = 'k2' AND t1.VALUE > 10)

crit: where k1 > 5 AND k2 > 10
=> 1 self-join needed
Select t1.S# 
from ATTR t1 
inner join ATTR t2 on t1.S# = t2.S#
where (t1.KEY = 'k1' AND t1.VALUE > 5)
        AND
      (t2.KEY = 'k2' AND t2.VALUE > 10)

crit: where k1 > 5 AND k2 > 10 AND k3 > 20
=> 2 self-joins needed
Select t1.S# 
from ATTR t1 
inner join ATTR t2 on t1.S# = t2.S#
inner join ATTR t3 on t1.S# = t3.S#
where (t1.KEY = 'k1' AND t1.VALUE > 5)
        AND
      (t2.KEY = 'k2' AND t2.VALUE > 10)
        AND
      (t3.KEY = 'k3' AND t3.VALUE > 20)

crit: where (k1 > 5 OR k2 > 10) AND (k1 > 10 OR  K3 > 20)
=> 1 self-join needed
Select t1.S# 
from ATTR t1 
inner join ATTR t2 on t1.S# = t2.S#
where ( (t1.KEY = 'k1' AND t1.VALUE > 5) OR (t1.KEY = 'k2' AND t1.VALUE > 10) )
        AND
      ( (t1.KEY = 'k1' AND t1.VALUE > 10) OR (t2.KEY = 'k3' AND t2.VALUE > 20) )

crit: where (k1 > 5 AND k2 > 10) or (k1 > 10 OR K3 > k4)
and so on
=> ??
```

I have no set limitations on number of atomic expressions (i.e. smallest boolean expression), except that they be combined
using only AND OR NOT. But I can happily set a limit (say 10-20 atoms) if that allows some cool algo. I am sure all RDBMS also have some basic limits. I am also thinking the XOR case could be folded into AND, and NOT is not material for the problem.

I am using a columnr database.

Thanks a lot

EDIT#2 -- added some sample data

```
S#  KEY VALUE
1   k1  1
1   k2  5
1   k3  10
1   k4  20
2   k1  10
2   k2  20
2   k3  30
2   k4  40
2   k5  50
3   k2  11
3   k4  22
3   k6  33
3   k8  44
3   k10 55
and so  on
```

In about 500 mln rows, there are about 900 distinct keys in total. Most "records" utilize about 50-60 different keys. The actual table has in all about 20 columns, including audit trail info. I have reduced them here to keep the problem focused.

Comment: I don't understand. Your "joins" aren't joins at all; you haven't specified the join condition. How does it connect t1 to t2? Do you mean a cross join? 

Can you give some examples *with data*?

Comment: @RossPresser my mistake, fixed. It is basically join on S# column.

Comment: @RossPresser for data, I am not sure if that would help. I am building a query language for a specific data model, and need to generate the SQL. But as it may help to visualize, I have added some data

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: My objective is to generate concrete queries, but at this stage (where I am only annotating the AST) I want to defer DBMS tieup to the extent possible. For a test case I would use SAP HANA and Postgres. My underlying data model is very, very plain.

Answer (score 0):

In general, every Key-Value criteria (eg `Key = 'k1' AND Value > 5`) with an `AND` operand will require a separate table look-up.
Once you work out how to parse your criteria (eg *where k1 > 5 AND k2 > 10*), you will be able to generate the SQL code required.

You don't have to explicitly use `JOIN` keyword. You can instead use `EXISTS`, which may be somewhat simpler to read. Here's an example based on criteria you provided as an example:

```
where (k1 > 5 OR k2 > 10) AND (k1 > 10 OR K3 > 20)
```

```sql
SELECT t.s#
FROM ATTR t
WHERE 1=1
-- KVP on left side of the AND
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ATTR t1
    WHERE t.S# = t1.S# -- Join sub-query to parent query
    AND (
        (t1.Key = 'k1' AND t1.Value > 5)
        OR
        (t1.Key = 'k2' AND t1.Value > 10)
        )
)
-- KVP on right side of the AND
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ATTR t1
    WHERE t.S# = t1.S# -- Join sub-query to parent query
    AND (
        (t1.Key = 'k1' AND t1.Value > 10)
        OR
        (t1.Key = 'k3' AND t1.Value > 20)
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. In my use case there is no one to read it - it generates and compiles the SQL. For that reason, I would appreciate some clarity on the "in general" part so that I could address whatever corner cases if any.